# Log Pulling and Rotating in Windows

Tags: windows, rotation, logging

Does anyone know of a good commercial or open source solution for pulling and rotating application logs from a bunch of disparate servers to a central server where you can catalog them by year/month/date/hour etc... this needs to be something that will work on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) but haven't personally used it.

Answer (score 0):

this page has some info on tools, http://www.dotnetlogging.com/comparison/ that can do this to some degree

Answer (score 0):

I've heard really great things about flume: https://github.com/cloudera/flume/wiki